# Install spyder 4 in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, python, ide, spyder

I just want to install spyder in its lastest version. I'm running on ubuntu 20.04. First i tried installing anaconda but I didn't like it because I don't want to use anaconda environment. So i uninstalled anaconda and now i want to install just spyder and upgrade it to it lastest version. By the moment I can run spyder 3, but it doesn't recognize me main packages. Like, for example, pandas. Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me Ubuntu 20.04:

1. Install Sypder 3 from linux terminal:
   `sudo apt install spyder`
2. Then upgrade to Spyder 5:
   `sudo python3 -m pip install --upgrade spyder`

You will have both Spyder 3 and Spyder 5 running side by side.  You can choose to keep both or delete one (or delete both!)

Answer (score 1):

Anaconda makes your life very easy in terms of managing packages. I assume that when you said you didn't like Anaconda environment you mean "Navigator". Sure not the best way to manage packages,but you don't have to use it. You can simply use conda on your terminal. When doing so you don't always have to worry about which dependencies you need, conda figures that out for you (in most cases).

Answer (score 1):

My approach feels a bit overkill but it worked like a charm, and I didn't find an other way. I wanted to use pipenv and *not* anaconda.

I used `pipenv` to manage venvs and isolate the environment where I would install spyder (similar to creating an environment dedicated to spyder in anaconda).

First, install pipenv :
`pip install pipenv`

After that I created a directory where I'd initialize my spyder env using pipenv :

```bsh
cd
mkdir spyder
```

Then I initialized the venv :
`pipenv install`
and installed spyder :
`pipenv install spyder`

To run spyder, you need to activate the venv first :

```bsh
pipenv shell
spyder &
```

or ask pipenv to run the command using the venv :

```bsh
pipenv run spyder &
```

This has the downside of creating two rather useless `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock` files, but the upside of having spyder installed in an isolated environment, without Anaconda.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already installed Spyder using `sudo apt install spyder`, it's recommended to just update using `pip install --upgrade spyder`.

Before that make sure you have installed `pip`, if not, use this command to install it:

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```